# Solve the equation $3x^2+5x \equiv -1357 \pmod{7919}$

Tags: number-theory

Solve the modular equation $3x^2+5x \equiv -1357 \pmod{7919}$.

Is there anybody help me with this ? I have thought several times but not to find out the solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as the quadratic equation $\; 3x^2+5x+1357=0$ in the finite field $\mathbf F_{7919}$.

Its discriminant should have a square root in this field. Now $\;\Delta=5^2-4\cdot 3\cdot1357 =-1629=-421$. Now we'll use quadratic reciprocity to determine whether $\Delta$ is a square in $\mathbf F_{7919}$:
$$\newcommand{\leg}[2]{\biggl(\frac{#1}{#2}\biggr)}
\leg{-421}{7919}=\leg{-1}{7919}\leg{421}{7919}=\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\tfrac{7918}2}\leg{421}{7919}=-\leg{421}{7919}.$$
Now $421$ is also prime, and
\begin{align}
\leg{421}{7919}&=\leg{7919}{421}\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\tfrac{7918\cdot 420}4}=\leg{7919}{421}=\leg{\overbrace{341}^{11\cdot 31}}{421}=\leg{11}{421}\leg{31}{421} \\
&=\leg{421}{11}\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\!\frac{420\cdot10 }4}\leg{421}{31}\bigl(-1\bigr)^{\frac{420\cdot 30}4}=\underbrace{\leg{3}{11}}_{=\,1}\leg{1}{31}=1
\end{align}
Therefore, $\;\displaystyle\leg{\Delta}{7919}=-1$, and the quadratic equation has no root in $\mathbf F_{7919}$.

Answer (score 3):

Because we work modulo $7919$ which is prime, we are working in a field. All equation will henceforth be understood as being modulo $7919$.

Rewrite as $$3x^2 + 5x + 1357 =0$$

Apply the solution formula for the quadratic: the discriminant is $b^2-4ac= 25 - 4\times 3 \times 1357 = 7498$

Using [quadratic reciprocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) or a symbolic calculator (Maple, Wolframalpha etc) we can find that $7498$ is not a square modulo $7919$,
so that the quadratic has no solutions in this finite field.

Comment: It is the *discriminant*.